# Custom UIStoryboardSegue can't use presentViewController:

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I need to update my universal app to push a tableview on iPhone, but present it modally on iPad (since a full screen tableview is ugly).  I thought this would be a nice chance to use a custom UIStoryboardSegue but I can't get the iPad to display the content.

The first time I try to present, the completion block is called as well as viewDidLoad in destination.  After that it throws a warning:

> Attempt to present < UINavigationController: 0x7fa0be045a80 > on < WalkthroughNavigationController: 0x7fa0bb8d0f70 > whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I've confirmed that WalkthroughNavigationController is in fact in the view hierarchy, however.  And the entire point of this code is to add the navigation controller to the hierarchy.

Is presentViewController not supported in a segue?

```
-(void)perform{
    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController*)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destination = (UIViewController*)self.destinationViewController;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM_PHONE()){
        // This works with no problem
        [source.navigationController pushViewController:destination animated:YES];
    } else {
        UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:destination];
        // I've tried various combinations of source, source.view.window, source.navigation controller here.  None of them show the modal view.
        [source.navigationController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:^{
            ALog(@"Nothing appeared.");
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a custom segue triggered by the previous tableview.  Everything is setup in the storyboard.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. `perform` is triggered by the segue. Well this line `[source.navigationController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:` is invalid since, like I said, you need to present from a view controller on the view hierarchy...not the nav controller.

Comment: The top view controller should be presenting new view controllers, not previous ones. The view hierarchy is a stack, you can only push and pop from the top.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (other than the if statement needs to be if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)).

Comment: @rdelmar If it works for you, there must be something else wrong in the OP's code. The source isn't on the view hierarchy for some other reason...

Comment: @arsenius How have you "confirmed that WalkthroughNavigationController is in fact in the view hierarchy"?

Comment: It seems that presentViewController: doesn't work at all from this view controller, as I've tested it in viewDidAppear.  I must have a larger issue at play.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I confirmed it because I can see it, and because its view.window is not nil.